# Is it possible to access the current 'to create' obj in constructor?

Tags: c++, object, constructor

I am currently writing a tree class and want to implement a constructor for creating a tree with a certain dimension and depth:

```
public:
    tree();                           // empty constructor
    tree(int dimension, int depth);   // constructing an empty tree
    // ...
    void            newNode(node<T>* const&, T const&);
    // ...
  private:
    unsigned int mNumNodes;
    node<T>      *mRoot;


template<typename T>
tree<T>::tree(int dimension, int depth):
  // member vars
{
  // other constructing stuff
  this->newNode(0, parent);
}
```

apparently something like that is not possible, but as I wrote a good working function for adding new nodes to a specific parent with a specific value it would be nice to use it.

BUT: this method needs access to the current object.

Maybe there is some kind of solution working for me neither pointing to the obj is possible, nor any other kind of access.

Comment: Why not `this->newNode(mRoot, parent);` ?

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: because tree is not construced as a pointer and there is: `no matching function for call to ‘tree<std::basic_string<char> >::newNode(int, node<std::basic_string<char> >*&)’`

Comment: @NathanOliver therefor I would have to paste a 80 lines long node header.

Comment: @hGen - Re *because tree is not construced as a pointer* -- If by that you mean the `this` pointer, it most certainly is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't the constructor. At the point execution enters the body of the constructor, the object is constructed as a `tree<std::basic_string<char> >`. This means you can use the object as an instance of that class in the body of your constructor.

The problem with using an object as such in a constructor is if the actual object being constructed is derived class of the class at hand. It's that knowledge that doesn't exist yet in the constructor of the parent class. It's best not to call virtual functions from within a constructor. It's generally okay to call a non-virtual member function from within a constructor. Another problem is that derived class constructors might change things in the parent class.

That's not what's happening here. The problem here is the use of zero as a `node<T>* const&`. This won't work, period. If it did work, you could change the value of zero.

Based on the incomplete code you have posted, getting rid of the ampersand in the declaration of the first argument to `newNode` will do the trick.

Comment: Well yes actually the problem was that i initialized the data of a node with `0` by default when creating a new node, so I tried to fill a std::string with a 0.